# IIS Directory listing doesn't reconize .mkv files

Tags: iis, download, directory-listing, mkv

I use the directory listing function in IIS to upload a bunch of files for friends and family to easy access and download.

My problem is that .mkv files it lists but when you click it i get a 'The page cannot be found'.

Ive tried relocating the file and renaming it but i get the same error each time. Why does it do this? Its only my .mkv files everything else works perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll just add this section for others seeking the same answer:
"1) Select the site to configure in IIS, right click and select "Properties"
2) Under HTTP Headers Tab, select "File Types" under the MIME Map section and select "New Type"
3) Type ".flv" as the associated extension and "video/x-flv" as the content type.
4) Select "OK" and you're ready to fly!"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

have you added the mkv mime type for your IIS server?

[Adding Mime Type Walk through](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/rymoore/adding-flv-mime-type-in-iis-4198)

use mkv and "video/x-matroska" where the example uses FLV and the flv mime type.

Answer (score 3):

IIS doesn't like to serve files with extensions it doesn't know the MIME type for.  This keeps someone from, say, getting web.config files (and thus, often, SQL server login info and such) from some site that wasn't extra careful about setting up permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Provided answers will allow IIS to serve .mkv files. However, an alternative mime type can be used - `video/webm`. This will allow some browsers to play the content, rather than downloading it.

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27243561/2780791).