# How to play MKV file in browser?

Tags: html5-video, mkv

I have a video file in **MKV** format, i want to play that file in the browser without converting, how can i play this file format in browser?

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mkv" type="video/mkv">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

i want this file to be played in full screen mode always. My browser is chrome.

Comment: Chrome should play MKV well. is the path correct ? and what's the Chrome version ?

Comment: Yes path is correct , chrome version is 27.0.1453.110

Comment: I'm asking Chrome's version. Another question shows Chrome can play MKV well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622726/html5-video-can-play-mkv-files ; what's your OS ?

Comment: try <video width="320" height="240" src="movie.mkv" controls></video>

Comment: This is the file i'm playing http://www.auby.no/files/video_tests/h264_720p_hp_3.1_600kbps_aac_mp3_dual_audio_harry_potter.mkv

Comment: there seems to be something wrong with your video or the server of the video. I tried with another video and it worked.

Comment: Parthik can you share that video.

Answer (score 20):

It will refuse to play Matroska if the type attribute is set to `video/x-matroska`. Try removing the type attribute completely.

After some experimentation with this issue, I've found the best solution is to set the mime type to `video/webm`.

Comment: If i set content-type for *.mkv file as contenty-type = video/webm video and audio working in chrome.
In IE, Firefox this still does not work.

Comment: Type `video/webm` worked for me on a Samsung TV. I did not work on any other browser I tested (Chrome, Safari, Firefox) on iPhone. On desktop I have image but no sound on Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

I think Chrome doesn't play .mkv videos.

By the way, 'type' is mime-type, and mkv's mime type is `video/x-matroska`.

Try:

```
source src="movie.mkv" type="video/x-matroska"
```

If this works, maybe the sound will be muted, so you can try `type="video/mp4"`.

Comment: This does not work, but upper post from Matt working well at least in chrome (in IE and Firefox not).

Answer (score 2):

I added the IIS Mime Type as (.mkv - video/webm) over the IIS option and it worked fine.

Comment: With Chrome? which version?

Comment: Why isn't your aswer the first? Worked perfecty.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use video with path `.mkv`

```html
<!-- mkv -->
  <video width="320" height="240" controls src="assets/animation.mkv"></video>
<!-- mp4 -->
  <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="assets/animation.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
```

if you do not understand, click on link

[Play Code](https://playcode.io/665842/)